# Emacs 24 not finding system fonts

Tags: emacs, fonts

Emacs doesn't offer me the possibility of installing several of the system fonts that I have. It only offers Courier and Lucida. Other programs, like LibreOffice, have no problem in using my system fonts, like DejaVu and such.

I've tried putting

```
(set-face-attribute ':font Monaco)

(set-face-attribute 'default nil :font "Ubuntu Mono")
```

or

```
(set-face-attribute ':font "Monaco")
```

to no avail.

What can I do?

Comment: It looks like your Emacs has only bitmap font support and not Truetype support. What OS/distribution are you running Emacs on? Where does the binary come from?

Answer (score 0):

Exactly, I only have these ugly fonts.

I am running Ubuntu 13.04, the binary comes from the official ftp server, http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/emacs/

I compiled it with ./configure, make, make install. The rest of it works.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing you can do with the combination Ubuntu 13.04 + emacs24. I had the same problem and searched for a solution in vain.

Either run emacs23, or try with Ubuntu 13.10, which was recently released.